# Incompatibility (conflicts) in installing pygeocoder

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I cannot install `pygeocoder`. How can I solve this conflict?
I have tried `pip install` and `conda install`. In theory it seems to be installed, but the Jupyter notebook cannot find it.

with `conda install -c daviskirk pygeocoder`, I see the message:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining wincertstore:   6%|███████▎                                                                                                                        | 2/35 [00:00<00:00, 127.99it/s]
Examining setuptools:  11%|██████████████▉                                                                                                                    | 4/35 [00:00<00:01, 23.63it/s]
Examining certifi:  43%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████                                                                            | 15/35 [00:00<00:00, 23.63it/| -
Comparing specs that have this dependency:   0%|                                                                                                                       | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]\
failed                                                                                                                                                                                       /
                                                                                                                                                                                             -
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

    - pygeocoder -> python=3.5
      - pygeocoder -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

    Your python: conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005

    If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
    When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
    not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
    change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
    that.

    The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



    Package wheel conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> wheel
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> wheel
    Package requests conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> requests[version='>=1.0']
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> requests
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> requests
    Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> requests[version='>=1.0'] -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.24'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> openssl=1.0 -> ca-certificates
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.24'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> openssl=1.0 -> ca-certificates
    Package pip conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip
    Package certifi conflicts for:
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']
    pygeocoder -> requests[version='>=1.0'] -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17']
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
    pygeocoder -> requests[version='>=1.0'] -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.24'] -> certifi
    Package msgpack-python conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
    Package setuptools conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> setuptools
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> setuptools
    Package wincertstore conflicts for:
    pygeocoder -> python=3.5 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
    conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
```

---

#### Configuration Details

- Windows 10
- Anaconda
- Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that that `pygeocoder` is only available for Python 3.5:

> ````
>    - pygeocoder -> python=3.5  
>    - pygeocoder -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
>
> Your python: conda-forge/win-64::python==3.6.7=he025d50_1005 ```
> ````

The best practice solution for this is to create a new env, instead of installing in the **base** Anaconda env. I recommend doing this with a YAML file and including everything you expect to need from the start, rather than adding packages *ad hoc*.

**pygeocoder_env.yml**

```
name: pygeocoder_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - daviskirk
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.5
  - pygeocoder
  - ipykernel    # needed to use this env as a Jupyter kernel
```

To create this env:

```
conda env create -f pygeocoder_env.yml
```

Note that you should still launch Jupyter from your **base** env, but when you create a new notebook you can select to use this new env as a kernel:

```
conda activate base
jupyter notebook
```

If the env doesn't show up as a kernel option, then you probably need to install `nb_conda_kernels`:

```
conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels
```

Comment: Funnily enough the source for pygeocoder doesn't mandate that compatibility range, so this is probably a Conda packaging problem. https://bitbucket.org/xster/pygeocoder/src/default/setup.py